# PNG won't display in classic asp site

Tags: asp-classic, png

I've got an ASP page and try to show the FF logo image on it and it won't display. It won't even show if I copy it local; only seems to be this particular PNG file:

```
<p><img src="http://sfx-images.mozilla.org/firefox/3.6/468x60_orange.png" alt="Spread Firefox Affiliate Button" /></p>
```

Page URL:
    https://english.ttu.edu/fyc/testpng.asp

**It was ... It was  ADBLOCk!**

Comment: It works fine for me on that URL.

Comment: Looks to be working. Is it your browser?

Comment: Uhm, I can see it? (Firefox 3.5.8)

Comment: Broken now, missing the `<p><`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADBLOCK. Doh! I need to get my fricken extensions in order.